# How to put a templated class into a list and save the type

Tags: c++

If I have the following class:

```
class Animal {
  ...
  int GetSize() const { return _size; }
  void SetSize(int size) { _size = size; }
  ...
private:
  int _size;
};
```

and I create a Converter class that can be called like this:

```
Animal* elephant = new Animal(...);
Converter* c = new Converter<Animal, int>(&Animal::GetSize, &Animal::SetSize);
c->Set(elephant, "50");
```

Assuming the converter template class would need the type of the object and the type of the field we're going to pass to it.

This isn't too big of a problem, you can just convert the string back to the original type and call the setter:

```
template <typename ObjectType, typename ValueType>
class Converter {
  ...
  void Set(ObjectType* obj, ValueType value) {
    std::stringstream ss(value);
    T newValue;
    ss >> newValue;
    (obj->*_setter)(newValue);
  }
  ...
  typedef void (ObjectType::*SetterType)(ValueType);
  SetterType setter;
  ...
};
```

The problem is putting these converter classes into a container of some kind.  Perhaps something like:

```
std::map<std::string, Converter*> fields;
fields["size"] = new Converter<Animal, int>(&Animal::GetSize, &Animal::SetSize);
```

First thoughts went to a abstract base class, but then you can't get the original type out of the base class, which means you can't do the string conversion.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Slight clarification.  The idea is to create a map with converters of different types, like this:

```
fields["size"] = new Converter<Animal, int>(&Animal::GetSize, &Animal::SetSize);
fields["growth"] = new Converter<Animal, double>(&Animal::GetGrowth, &Animal::SetGrowth);
```

Comment: Does `std::map<std::string, Converter<Animal, int>*>` not do what you're looking for?

Comment: I suppose there is an ulterior motive for using all those `new`s there, because from what can be gathered from these small snippets, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

This line will not compile:

```
Converter* c = new Converter<Animal, int>(&Animal::GetSize, &Animal::SetSize);
```

The problem is that `Converter*` is not a valid type. `Converter<Animal, int>*` is. You can not create  pointer without specifying the template parameters. This also solves your other problem - you don't have to store the type in any other way but in the type of the pointer.

Comment: This is 100% correct, but I edited the original question to explain why this isn't my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define a base class for all your converters, and let your template converters derived from your base class.

Most of the time, interface can help.

Comment: The problem is when you want to convert the string back to the original type, you don't know what the type is any more when you only have a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @fizixx But the overloaded functions in your converter will have the knowledge, right?